# How to handle many users in slack app for in Python? How to use the multiple tokens?

Tags: python, oauth, slack-api, slack

I am making a slack bot. I have been using python slackclient library to develop the bot. Its working great with one team. I am using Flask Webframework.

As many people add the app to slack via "Add to Slack" button, I get their ***bot_access_token***.

Now
**how should I run the code** with so many Slack tokens. Should I store them in a list and then traverse using for loops for all token! But this was is not good as I may not be able to handle the simultaneous messages or events I receive Or "its a good way".
Any other way if its not?

Comment: The Python slackclient which i am using [python_slackclient](https://github.com/slackhq/python-slackclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the real-time API, you'll need one WebSocket open per team. Yes, you would typically use a loop to establish these connections. Depending on the way `slackclient` works, you might need to start each in a separate thread or process.

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments below, threading is to be preferred over multiple processes. Even better would be to use something lighter weight than threads, but at this point in your learning, I wouldn't bother over-optimizing here.

**SECOND EDIT**: It looks like `python-slackclient` has non-blocking reads, so you don't even need to use threads. E.g. the following will not block:

```
for team in teams:
    for event in team.client.rtm_read():
        # process the event for that team
```

(This assumes some sort of "team" object that contains an instance of `SlackClient`.)

Comment: How to start each connection in a separate thread? Could you please explain.

Comment: I think that's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I mean can you please list the python framework which I could use. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @smarx. I am a beginner in this field. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: I think that answer is incorrect, opening one RTM connection per process will be really ressource intensive. You can open hundreds of connection per process

Comment: I'll make an edit to emphasize that of the two options I mentioned, per-thread is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed need to

1. Store each team token. **Please remember to encrypt it**
2. When a team installs your app, create a new RTM connection. When your app/server restarts, loop across all your teams, open a RTM connection for each of them
3. each connection will receive events from that team, and that team only. You will not receive all notifications on the same connection

(maybe you are coming from Facebook Messenger bots background, where all notifications arrive at the same webhook ? That's not the case with Slack)

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm - In point 2 - I will use threading and will open connection RTM connections on each thread. Can it be done without threading?

Comment: I want to know that without threading will it create a lot of lag or will it work fine. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The idea is to open many RTM connection on the same process. For example, my app [Smooz](http://www.smooz.io) opens hundreds of RTM connections per process, without threading. There is no perceptible lag (unless of course you do a lot of I/O or computation server-side)